# Add favicon to JSF project and reference it in <link>

Tags: html, jsf, favicon

How do I add a favicon to a JSF project and reference it in `<link>` element?

I tried as below:

```
<h:head>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico"/>
    ...
</h:head>
```

However, it didn't show any favicon.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

A relative `href` is relative to the current request URI. Likely it resolved to an invalid URL. You need to prepend with the context path so that it becomes relative to the domain root.

Also, the `rel` has better to be `shortcut icon` to get it to work in older browsers too.

In case of using an `.ico` file, you also need to ensure that it's a **real** `.ico` file and not some `.bmp` renamed to `.ico`. You can generate one [here](http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/favicon/) based on several image formats. You can however also just use a `.png` or `.gif` file.

All in all, provided that the file is located in

```
WebContent
 |-- images
 |    `-- favicon.ico
 :
```

then this should do it:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="#{request.contextPath}/images/favicon.ico"/>
```

If you've however placed it as a JSF resource in the `/resources` folder as follows

```
WebContent
 |-- resources
 |    `-- images
 |         `-- favicon.ico
 :
```

which would make it accessible by `<h:graphicImage name="images/favicon.ico">`, then this should do it:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="#{resource['images/favicon.ico']}"/>
```

#### See also:

- [Wikipedia - Favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon)
- [How to reference CSS / JS / image resource in Facelets template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-css-js-image-resource-in-facelets-template)

Comment: Then you have to be more specific about the webbrowser used and the real URLs used. E.g. MSIE? Firefox? Etc. And does http://localhost:8080/contextname/images/favicon.ico return the image? Etc. Is the generated HTML source correct? Rightclick page and *View Source* etc. Do basic debugging, man :)

Comment: Aha, that's it. Everything is OK, but I don't know why, my project (made in eclipse) is published on http://localhost:13899/PORTAL/index.xhtml instead of http://localhost:8080/PORTAL/default.xhtml I changed the port manually and favicon works. Now I have to find out where to change the port forever. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 13):

I used the following and it works in both IE and Chrome

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="#{resource['images/favicon.ico']}" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Answer (score 6):

Since JSF uses the resources as a container for storing the image file folder, you can do the following;

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="#{request.contextPath}/resources/images/favicon.ico"/>
```

Comment: That's not mandatory. It's just a free choice. The OP isn't using the resources folder. Only when you would like to use `<h:outputStylesheet>` and/or `<h:outputScript>` and/or `@ResourceDependency`, then you **must** use the resources folder.

Comment: For targetting the icon (if stored in the images subdirectory of resources directory), you can also use `href="#{resource['images:favicon.ico']}"`

Comment: `href="#{request.contextPath}/resources/images/favicon.ico"` is more readible

Answer (score 4):

As a side note, I always include both of these when referencing a favicon:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://a.staticimageserver.com/img/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://a.staticimageserver.com/img/favicon.ico" />
```

Comment: The first one works on all browsers, the second one fails on MSIE. Just remove the second one. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

Comment: nice. you just saved me one line per resource for the rest of my days.